# Count of row values that are outside the limits

Tags: r

I am trying to compare row values in one data frame against threshold limits read from a second data frame. I would like to get the count of values "per row" in dat that are above the upper limit (UL from limits df), and below the lower limit (LL from limits df)

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(12, 23, 45), B = c(54, 73, 25), C = c(47, 52, 38))

limits <- data.frame(NAME = c('A', 'B', 'C'), UL = c(34, 12, 40), LL = c(55, 80, 50))
```

How do I reference the values from the limits table in the `apply` function below?

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) sum(x < limits$LL | x > limits$UL))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your values in `limits$LL` are greater than the values in `limits$UL`. Is that wanted by you? If yes, what logic is that the lower limit is greater than the upper limit?

Comment: Did you mean this: `apply(dat, 1, function(x, l) { sum(x < l$LL | x > l$UL)},limits)`?
Btw: Do you really want the values higher UL AND lower LL? Right now, you're using the or-operator...

Comment: My mistake, lower limit limits$LL should be less than upper limit limits$UL. I used a bad example of limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` like below:

```
rownames(limits) <- limits[,"NAME"]
list.counts <- sapply(colnames(dat), function(n) {
                      dat.n <- dat[,n]
                      limits.n <- limits[n,]
                      sum(dat.n < limits.n[,"LL"] | dat.n > limits.n[,"UL"])})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like that: (with `for` rather than `apply` and taking into consideration @jogo's comment, so changing `UL` and `LL` in your example):

```
ile <- ncol(dat)
nazwy <- colnames(dat)
for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){

    ktory <- which(limits$NAME==nazwy[i])
    ul <- limits$UL[ktory]
    ll <- limits$LL[ktory]
    ile[i] <- sum(dat[, i] <=ul & dat[, i]>=ll)

    if(i==ncol(dat)) names(ile) <- nazwy
}
ile

> ile
A B C 
1 3 1
```